# Solving PDE's with terms of type $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\left(\frac{\partial^m T}{\partial y^m}\right)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Consider a differential equation of the following type:
$$\sum_n a_n \frac{\partial^n T}{\partial x^n}+\sum_m b_m \frac{\partial^m T}{\partial y^m}=0$$
($a_n$ and $b_m$ are independent of $x$ and $y$). This can be solved by separation of variables and using the fact that a linear combination of known solutions is a new solution.
But, what if the differential equation was of the form
$$\sum_{m,n}a_{n,m}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\left(\frac{\partial^m T}{\partial y^m}\right)=0$$
The differential equation looks similar to the one before it: we can use the principle of superposition here. However, we cannot use the technique of separation of variables to simplify our task. So, how can we solve such a problem?

This question might seem a bit too general, so let me offer a simpler problem: Solve the following differential equation: $$\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\right) + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}=0.$$
(If you are confused about why I am claiming separation of variables does not lead to any progress, take the above equation. If we write $T(x)=X(x)Y(y)$ then we get: $Y\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial y}+X\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial y^2}=0$. How do we proceed using separation of variables? From here I do not see any obvious way to write it as $F(x)+G(y)=0$)

Comment: I had posted a similar question before... However, the PDE there was slightly different there (the principle of superposition did not apply). Also, I discovered that knowing this particular PDE's solutions is more relevant than the last (that is the reason why I deleted the last post). Thanks for any help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T(x, y)$ is a continuous and smooth function and you have periodic boundary conditions, you can use the Fourier transform to simplify it. Essentially, the method to solve this problem depends on the boundary conditions.

However, this equation can be simplified using the d'Alembert substitution:

$$ u = x - y \tag 1$$
$$ v = x + y \tag 2$$

Now $T$ is a function of $u$ and $v$. By partially differentiating $T(u, v)$, we get:

$$T_x = T_u u_x + T_v v_x \tag 2$$
$$T_y = T_u u_y + T_v v_y \tag 3$$

$$T_{xx} = T_{uu} (u_x)^2 + T_u u_{xx} +
         T_{vv} (v_x)^2 + T_v v_{xx} \tag 4$$
$$T_{yy} = T_{uu} (u_y)^2 + T_u u_{yy} +
         T_{vv} (v_y)^2 + T_v v_{yy} \tag 5$$

$$T_{xy} = T_{uu} u_x u_y + T_u u_{xy} +
         T_{vv} v_x v_y + T_v v_{xy} \tag 6$$

Since $u_{xx} = v_{xx}= u_{yy} = v_{yy}=u_{xy} = v_{xy}=0$ and $u_x = v_x = v_y = 1$, as well as $u_y=-1$, we get:

$$T_{xx} =  T_{uu} + T_{vv} \tag 7$$
$$T_{yy} =  T_{uu} + T_{vv} \tag 8$$
$$T_{xy} = -T_{uu} + T_{vv} \tag 9$$

When we plug the above expressions into equation $T_{xx} + T_{xy}+T_{yy}=0$ we get the simplified equation:

$$ T_{uu} + 3 T_{vv}=0 \tag{10}$$

We can get rid of the constant $3$ by doing the substitution $v=\sqrt3 w$:

$$ T_{uu} + T_{ww}=\nabla ^2 T = 0 \tag{11}$$

So in the end, the Laplace equation needs to be solved.

Comment: If we write $T(x)=X(x)Y(y)$ then we get: $Y\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial y}+X\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial y^2}=0$. How do we proceed using separation of variables? (I do not see any obvious way to write it as $F(x)+G(y)=0$)

Comment: Ah, you are right, the mixed derivative is the problem. Can't even use an integration factor to simplify it. Still, depending on the BC's, a method would be selected. Integral transformations would be a good choice if the boundary conditions were proper. I will modify my answer.

Comment: If we assume the boundary conditions are $T(0)=T(l)=0$ for some $l$, how would you attempt to solve the equation (could you write it in your answer)? Also any book recommendations on how to solve such equations?

Comment: If a PDE is homogeneous and all of the boundary conditions are zero, the solution to the PDE is zero. Is it OK if I try to solve for for instance: $T(0,y) \neq 0, T(1,y) \neq 0, T(x,0)=T_y(x,0)=0$ ?

Comment: Yes, you can do so...go ahead

Comment: While I was solving an example I had in mind with the Laplace transform method, I noticed the solution after using the inverse Laplace transform was in the form of waves in the complex domain. That is when I realized that the original equation could be simplified with the change of variables. I wrote that down in my answer. Can you solve your problem now?

Comment: As for literature, a really good and concise book on PDEs is "Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers" by Stanley J. Farlow. You got the integration transformation methods there explained for solving PDEs along with a lot of other methods. Most likely, you can download the book for free from the internet.